# View pager android with single background picture

Tags: android, view, pager

Is it possible to have one picture as a panorama background of a viewpager, without having to cut the image into 3 and put each of the 3 images as a background for each of the different views?

Like the home screen of android.

Comment: You could do some in-code image manipulation to cut the image into (1 / viewPagerPages) pieces.  Don't think there's anything built in for this without a library of some kind.

Comment: The Hacienda must be built!

Comment: Not sure what you are cutting up here.  This question needs more description, currently it's too vague.  50000 foot answer, make the Layout have a background image and make the viewpager background transparent, but with out any details a real answer can't be given.

Comment: Go to android home screen. Observe. Swipe left. Swipe right. Swipe right.Observe. This is the functionality I want. A viewpager, that has the same background image panned across the 3 views.

I don't want a slideshow. I don't want continuous panorama either like in gallery. There needs to be 3 distinct swipe views. Each of the 3 views will have 1/3 of the background image each.

Please ask me what other details are needed, if this isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

You want a horzontal Parallax .
[this](https://github.com/Narfss/ParallaxEverywhere) library should to the trick, or at least get you on track.